# Differential Equation $\ln(y') = x - y - e^y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution to this initial value problem on the largest interval.
$$\ln(y') = x - y - e^y, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y(1)=0.$$

So this differential equation is not linear and not homogeneous. I first tried finding a solution to the associated homogeneous equation $$\ln(y') = - y - e^y$$$$\iff y' =e^{-(y+e^y)}$$
which I was able to solve by separating the variables. The general solution I thus found is $$y(x) = C \,\, \ln(\ln(x)).$$

Now I wonder how to find the solution to the original non-homogeneous equation.
Can anyone share a hint or general strategy for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First thing to notice is $y = \ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{y}\right)$
$$
\ln(y') = x - \ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{y}\right) -\mathrm{e}^{y}
$$
then we have
$$
\ln\left(y'\mathrm{e}^{y}\right) = x - \mathrm{e}^{y}
$$
using the sub $v = \mathrm{e}^{y}$ leads to
$$
\ln(v') = x- v
$$

thus
$$
v' = \mathrm{e}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-v}
$$

hence
$$
\mathrm{e}^{v} = \mathrm{e}^{x}+C\implies v = \ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+C\right)
$$
and subbing in for y
$$
y(x) = \ln\left[\ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{x}+C\right)\right]
$$
now we have $y(1) = 0$ which means
$$
y(1) = 0 = \ln\left[\ln\left(\mathrm{e}+C\right)\right]
$$
therefore $C = 0$ so the solution is actually 
$$
y(x) = \ln(x)
$$
you could check that the solution you found does not hold for the original equation.

Comment: Ahh thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Now how would I determine the largest interval on which y is a solution of the differential equation? I assume it would be $(0, \infty)$, right?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the most sensible first step is to remove that logarithm, at which point the equation is separable.

$$y'=\dfrac{e^x}{e^{y+e^y}}$$
$$e^ye^{e^y}dy=e^xdx$$
$$e^{e^y}=e^x+C$$
$$e^{e^0}=e^1+C,C=0$$

So the solution looks to be $x=e^y$